# Inserir dados na resposta servidor node.js

Tags: node.js

Seguinte pessoal, rodei sem problemas o exemplo de hello world em node.js disponibilizado no express.js, acesso ele normal no meu localhost:7000.

É possível eu manipular a resposta de hello World, como por exemplo tamanho da fonte, centralizado etc...e exibir uma imagem junto?

Código

```
// Carregue o módulo http para criar um servidor HTTP.
var http = require('http');

// Configura nosso servidor HTTP para responder com Olá Mundo a todas as solicitações.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  // Define os parâmetros de cabeçalho de resposta
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  // Envia uma resposta para o cliente com a mensagem Hello World
  response.end("Hello World\n");

});

// Define a porta 8000 onde será executado, o ip padrão é 127.0.0.1 / localhost
server.listen(3000);

// Imprime uma mensagem no servidor
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3000/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode sim. o método `res.send` é usado para enviar texto no corpo da respota ao cliente. Esse texto pode ser JSON, XML...
Para renderizar páginas usando o método `res.render`

exemplo Expressjs:

```
res.render('arquivoHTML',(err, html) => {
  res.send(html);
});
```

No exemplo acima o conteudo dentrodo de arquivoHTML será carregado para a variável html. em seguida o método `res.send` envia o conteudo. Lembres-se o código acima deve ser colocado numa rota.

Para servir um diretório com conteúdo estático (index.html,css,js), igual ao apache ou nginx use o middleware static do express.

Exemplo:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use('/',express.static('diretório'))
...
```

Quando acessar pelo navegador `localhost:7000/` ele entregará o conteudo dentro do diretório definido no `.static()`

Referência: [Entregando arquivos estáticos no Express](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/starter/static-files.html)

[app.render(view, [locals], callback)](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#res.render)